# Relativistic time dilation on Mars compared to Earth?

Tags: time, relativity, planets, time-dilation, semiclassical

What is the time dilation in Mars, compared to earth? Can we accurately calculate it? What information is needed to do these calculations?

Comment: Have you looked at [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) on Wikipedia?

Comment: Correct answer: certainly it can be calculated, but so utterly trivial that it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @dmckee could you provide some rough calculations of why it would be so small, and how small it would be (just in the order of magnitudes is enough)?

Comment: You are looking for the "weak field limit" to calculate the gravitational effect, and you can take both planets' orbital velocities relative the sun as a basic for computing the size of the special relativistic effect. I think the SR based effects will dominate, but I'm serious about not caring enough to bother.

Comment: @dmckee you cared enough to bother to tell us you did not care to bother. Why not just skip over Q's you do not care about.

Comment: @JohnDoe, were you interested in gravitational time dilation, time dilation from motion, or both?

Comment: @Aabaakawad I responded to give John the tools he needed to go forward on his own, and let him know wasn't going to perform the calculation for him to preempt further requests.

Comment: @dmckee OK, I get it, it just felt hostile to me.

Comment: @Aabaakawad our other sensible option here is to close the question for lack of research effort, so really in prodding Johm to attempt the calculation, dmckee was being more helpful than necessary... Though credit goes to Kyle for actually linking a relevant page.

Comment: @Asher it does not make sense to close this question due to lack of research. What would more research mean? If you want to, I can do some research and I can write about time dilation and mars but I would still not be able to do the calculations. The question would only be more verbose. There is no need for that. And if I study more, eventually it will be enough to make the calculations, but then the question is no longer necessary. So I can't understand how closing this would be helpful to anybody.

Comment: At this point "more research" would mean "any research at all," which should lead you straightforwardly to the equations you need. If you then don't know how to perform the calculations indicated by the equations, well... We're not a homework help site either. Perhaps you know an engineer or instructor who could teach you the calculus.

Comment: @dmckee Who are you to decide that an exercise is trivial?

Answer (score 4):

We can calculate the time dilation approximately using the weak field approximation. If the difference in the Newtonian gravitational potential between two points $A$ and $B$ is $\Delta\Phi$ then the weak field approximation tells us that the relative rate at which clocks at the two points tick is given by:

$$ \frac{\Delta t_A}{\Delta t_B} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2\Delta\Phi_{AB}}{c^2}} \tag{1} $$

Let's be clear about the notation and sign conventions. Take your example of Earth and Mars as an example. $\Delta\Phi_{AB}$ is the change in the potential energy going from the Earth ($A$) to Mars ($B$), and since in going from the Earth to Mars means the potential energy becomes less negative that means $\Delta\Phi_{AB} \gt 0$. That means the right hand side of equation (1) is less than one, so the fraction $\Delta t_A/\Delta t_B$ is less than one. This means time ticks more slowly on Earth than it does on Mars.

To calculate $\Delta\Phi$ simply:

1. calculate the (positive) potential energy change to leave the Earth's surface (staying at the same distance from the Sun)
2. calculate the (positive) potential energy change to move from the Sun-Earth istance outwards to the Sun Mars distance
3. calculate the (negative) potential energy change to descend to the surface of Mars (staying at the same distance from the Sun)

then add up the three potential energy changes to get the total $\Delta\Phi$ and plug it into equation (1). I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Strictly speaking this only calculate the gravitational time dilation and ignores the time dilation due to the orbital velocity of the Earth and Mars. In the weak field limit you can simply multiply together the time dilation due to gravity and orbital velocity.

Comment: "Weak" means that the escape velocities and the speeds are all <~ 0.1c. Couldn't the square root term be linearized as well?

Comment: From this answer, it should follow that time will 'tick' differently for two points on Earth, as well (just omitting steps 1 and 2 of calculating `ΔΦ`, since we are not leaving the planet). Is it so? If yes, is difference so small we can neglect it?

Comment: @FilippW. yes time varies with altitude and in fact this is easily measurable using atomic clocks.

Comment: I agree on linearizing the expression further. For simple estimates like this, the easier formula is $\frac{t_a}{t_b} = 1-\frac{\Delta\Phi}{c^2} = 1-\frac{g\Delta h}{c^2}$.  The next term is $\frac{(g\Delta h)^2}{2c^4}$ and obviously negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the constant of gravity ($6.67\times 10^{-11} m3/(kgs^2)$), $C$ the speed of light ($2.99792\times 10^8 m/s$), $M_S$ the mass of the sun ($1.9891\times 10^{30} kg$), $r_E$ the mean radius of the orbit of Earth ($1.496\times 10^{11} m$), $r_M$ the mean radius of the orbit of Mars ($2.2799\times 10^{11} m$), $ρ_E$ the mean radius of the Earth ($6.37\times 10^6 m$), and $ρ_M$ the mean radius of Mars ($3.3895\times 10^6 m$).

You need to calculate what the radius of a body would have to be to form a black hole (Schwarzschild radius) before you can calculate the effect of its gravity on time dilation.

Schwarzschild radius of Sun $$R_S=(2GM_S)/C^2 =2.95237\times 10^3 m$$

Time dilation from Sun’s gravity    $$Δt_S=1-\sqrt{(1-R/r_o )}$$  Earth: $9.86755\times 10^{-9}$   Mars: $6.47477\times 10^{-9}$
**Difference: $3.39278\times 10^{-9}$**

Orbital velocity    $$v_p=\sqrt{(GM_S)/r_o }$$  Earth: 2.97801E+4 m/sec Mars: 2.41231E+4 m/sec

Time dilation from orbital velocity $$Δt_v=1-\sqrt{1-(v_p/C)^2} $$  Earth: $4.93378\times 10^{-9}$   Mars: $3.23739\times 10^{-9}$    **Difference: $1.69639\times 10^{-9}$**

Schwarzschild radius of planet  $$R_P=(2GM_p)/C^2$$  Earth: $8.86409\times 10^{-3}$   Mars: $9.52445\times 10^{-4}$

Time dilation from planet’s gravity $$Δt_p=1-\sqrt{1-R_p/ρ_p}$$ Earth: $6.95769\times 10^{-10}$ Mars: $1.40499\times 10^{-10}$   **Difference: $5.55269\times 10^{-10}$**

Time dilation from planet's rotation is insignificant and varies with latitude, so I ignored it here.

I get about $5.64444\times 10^{-9}$ or about 1.78 seconds a year or 3.35 seconds a Mars year.

If you more properly use the dilations and not the deltas, you should multiply the gravitational and velocity sums.  It results in the same answer to a reasonable precision.